# Stripping newlines / blank spaces at the end from XML feed

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

We've got an xml feed that I need to strip newlines and trim the end whitespace from the fields. I generate the XML through the following:

```
Protected Sub GenerateXML(ByVal type As String)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim connStr As String = "database=M**********"
        Dim selectCommand As String
    If type = "standard" Then
        selectCommand = "select * from JobList where username = '" & username & "' and status in ('" & status & "','Cancelled', 'Assessed', 'Remove')"
    Else
        selectCommand = "select * from JobList where username = '" & username & " '"
    End If

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(selectCommand, conn)
        conn.Open()
        ds.DataSetName = "Locations"
        ds.Load(command.ExecuteReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, "Location")

        For Each r As DataRow In ds.Tables("Location").Rows
            If r("status") = "Assessed" Then
                r("status") = "Cancelled"
            End If
        Next
        ds.AcceptChanges()


        Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
        ds.WriteXml(Response.OutputStream)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Is there a way for me to run a replace through each line that goes in to the ds? Or am I going to have to generate the XML another way?

Thakns

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `XmlWriter` with the `Response.OutputStream` and then pass that to `WriteXml`  Here is the article on [Using the XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx3wa6ka.aspx).

My guess at the code would be:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = false;
settings.NewLineChars = "";


using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Response.OutputStream, settings))
{
   ds.WriteXml(writer);
}
```